# The "idd" attribute in html? Edit: can I use Javascript to get an element based off of a custom attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So there's this interesting thing I found. The "idd"(no that is not a typo) attribute. It looks like this in html:

```
<div idd="asdf1">some content</div>
<div idd="asdf2">some content</div>
<div idd="asdf3">some content</div>
<div idd="asdf4">some content</div>
```

Problem is, I've got no idea what it is for. On the website that I am working with it looks like it is the id attribute.

MY GOAL: I'd like to use the "idd" attribute to get the first div in Selenium. The best way that I can see is to run Javascript within Selenium to get the div because selenium doesn't have a way to get an element with a custom attribute. I haven't used Javascript in a while so, how would i go about doing this?

Comment: It's probably just sloppy coding

Comment: I would agree with John, it's sloppy poor coding. I know html5 allows custom attributes, but normally it's preceded by `data`, example would have been `data-idd`.

Comment: The idd tag doesnt exist. People often create new tags, but in this case, must be a mistake. Maybe there is a bucle creating the divs with the idd tag.

Comment: This seems an unlikely case considering the fact that the site does not use HTML5(I know). The problem that it is causing has to do with Selenium WebDriver, but I figure that I should figure out what it is for before complaining about it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several jquery and other plugins now use custom attributes to render their functionality; it is not limited to HTML5.

Xpath and css selectors work with custom attributes also, so the following xpath will get you the first `div` based on  it's `idd` value.

```
//div[@idd='asdf1']
```

Comment: If I'm understanding right, I should be able to get at it using Selenium's `By.xPath("xPath")` or `By.cssSelector("cssSelector")` functions. Unfortunatly,  the Xpath does not work very well at all. The good news is: the css selector 'idd~=[asdf1]' will find the element just fine.

Comment: Yes, you would use `By.xPath("//div[@idd='asdf1']")`. I have been successful with using xpath for custom attributes, strange that is not the case with you. What was your exact line of code?

Answer (score 2):

Copy-pasted (or iterated) typo? I've never heard of it.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, but when I saw it occur on multiple pages and then on different versions of the same site altogether, it seems that the attribute is used for something.